# How to change the folder of the uploaded image in ckeditor

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I have implement CKeditor with file manager. Its working fine without any change in file manager plugin. Now I need to change the file uploading path folder.

I need to change the `./userfiles` folder into  `localhost/myproject/uploads/editor_image`

How can I do that?

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Changing-default-upload-folder

Comment: I dont have the  config.cfm file

Comment: Which file manager do you use?

Comment: fckeditor-filemanager